# Typescript infer object keys based on array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create an object with specific keys based on the value of the array.

Here is the code:

```
type AllowedKeys = "foo" | "bar" | "baz"

interface Options {
    keys: AllowedKeys[]
}

interface AllTypesDeclaration {
    foo: string[];
    baz: object[];
    bar: number[];
}

function createObj(arg: Options): Pick<AllTypesDeclaration, typeof arg.keys[number]> {
    return {}
}

const myObj = createObj({ keys: ['baz'] })

// This should work:
myObj.baz

// This should fail:
myObj.foo
myObj.bar
```

As you can see I tried to do it using `Pick`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Demo: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwNIRAZygXigCIAzRRIqAH2ICMBDAJ0pqIYC8iAoLgSwDtgERiXoBjaAHkwwXon54A3lyiqoAa2w4AXLAQp0WXAG0AulwC%20PAUJHjo8OABVwEHABEIYuE3qz5UMpqUGSIujjAjAIA5mYA3CpqHLqItABWXsDxiaoMjLr8AK4AtrTC2VZcJIX8Yv78UGKMEH4QkukAFEzRutL1OACUugAKvGLqADyOLpAeXj6MfnL8ADRQoJCIJFDdAHSaJkWlwqYAfIE5UM3AhYwNilaVYvIRUMUg7WkEjc2tnx2KDRaXTGADkHFBpigFgGPAA9HCoE4ABa8PA4ZGIQpwNBQZCIRjqbRcd6fXYceGIlFoqAYrE4kL0XhwYmk9K7UIkj7svJAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need generics for that, otherwise the type of keys will not be restricted by the input.

```
function createObj<T extends AllowedKeys[]>(arg: { keys: T })
    : Pick<AllTypesDeclaration, typeof arg.keys[number]> {
    return {}
}
```